# Find random variable of double exponential

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let $X$ be a random variable with the double exponential distribution with the pdf
> $$f(x,\theta)=(2\theta)^{-2}e^{(-|x|/\theta)}.$$
> Consider the random variable $Y=c|X|$. Find the constant $c$ and integer number $r$ such that $Y \sim \chi^2(r)$.

I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laplace distribution (centred at $\mu=0$) has PDF $$f(x,\theta) = \frac{1}{2\theta}e^{-\frac{|x|}{\theta}}$$

and MGF (for $\theta>0$ and $\theta |t| < 1$)

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] &= \frac{1}{2\theta} \left (\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{tx+\frac{x}{\theta}}\, dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tx-\frac{x}{\theta}}\, dx \right ) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left (\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{u(\theta t +1)}\, du + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{u(\theta t-1)}\, du \right ) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left (\frac{1}{1 + \theta t} + \frac{1}{1 - \theta t} \right )\\
&= \frac{1}{1-\theta^{2}t^{2}}.
\end{align*}

---

Next, as homework, follow the example and (i) compute $\mathbb{E}[e^{ct|X|)}] = \frac{1}{1-c\theta t}$.

Then (ii) note that, if $Y \sim \chi^{2}(r)$, then $\mathbb{E}[e^{tY}] = \frac{1}{(1-2t)^{k/2}}$.

Finally (iii) match coefficients so that $c\theta = 2$ and $\frac{k}{2}=1$.